# Xcode version required to push a swift based app

Tags: ios, swift, appstore-approval, xcode6.1

I need to prepare my swift based app for appstore push.Is there any minimal requirement in the version of Xcode that is suitable(Currently I'm using Xcode 6.1) for pushing the App.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a